# Datepicker - Set maximum date to 18 years ago from current date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off">
```

**JS:**

```
var maxBirthdayDate = new Date();
maxBirthdayDate.setFullYear( maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear() - 18 );

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: maxBirthdayDate
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:**

```
https://jsfiddle.net/z13au9t6/
```

**PROBLEM:**
Although setting maxDate to 18 years ago is working, I cannot now select year below 1990 and months above August.

[image]

Comment: are you sure you don't want to set the minDate to 18 years ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `yearRange`. To make maintenance easier you can use ranges relative to the current date by using the `c` character in the format string, like this:

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: '-99:-18'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: But still, if you click on current date it set value of input

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  if you select year in your working example  then you can see issue. I am selecting 1922 and 1822 got selected.

Comment: You're right - that was due to the use of `c` n the `yearRange`. I've edited to remove that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  great.

Answer (score 3):

Use the year range property, set the month and date to the end of the year to go past august

```
var maxBirthdayDate = new Date();
maxBirthdayDate.setFullYear( maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear() - 18,11,31);
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: maxBirthdayDate,
  yearRange: '1950:'+maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear(),
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z13au9t6/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `yearRange` property as well like:

```
yearRange: '-100:+100',
```

It will set the year range to -100 years and +100 years. So you can able to select previous 100 years.